# Как дать доступ к полноценной системе линукс с рабочим окружением например GNOME через обычный браузер

Tags: linux, debian, hosting, gnome, remote-access

и так есть удалённая система допустим DEBIAN c рабочим столом GNOME
я хочу подключиться и управлять ей по средствам обычного интернет браузера допустим FIREFOX. Я хочу вводить в адресную строку браузера адрес хоста и попадать на рабочий стол GNOME открывающийся прямо в браузере или отдельным окном.

Comment: Зачем велосипед с браузером? Удаленка и так без проблем настраивается.

Comment: я думал на стеке отвечаю на вопрос как, а не задают вопрос зачем

Comment: Это уточнение. (вопросы тоже задают, тут не роботы, а живые люди) Ответ: скорее всего никак

Comment: если бы вопрос качался конкретно решения, я бы с радостью на него ответил. НИКАК не принимается

Comment: Сам браузер не даст. Хотя, лучше подожди понедельника, народу будет больше, может кто-то что-то стоящее напишет

Comment: почему не дас, надо просто настроить трансляцию удалённого рабочего стола через ip

Comment: Мне самому интересна подобная идея. Подожду какого-то ответа. Насколько я знаю, никто подобного не проворачивал, ставлю звездочку :) (если найдешь решение раньше ответа, добавь, интересна реализация)

Comment: Если ты проголосуешь за это воппос он быстрее найдет ответ

Comment: vnc over java на порту 5800?

Comment: "надо просто настроить трансляцию удалённого рабочего стола через ip", по протоколу, с которым браузер умеет работать. А на этот рабочий стол вам просто смотреть или в ту сторону тоже что-то передавать?

Comment: @L.F.C. Вообще гугл по запросу "x-server in browser" выдает много интересного. например английский SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556947/html5-javascript-x11-server В общем решения есть

Comment: Полноценный контроль над системой , мышкой хочу водить и все как в жизни бывает

Comment: Ну x-server как бы подразумевает свободный контроль мышкой и прочим. Потому что это стандарный удаленный рабочий стол для unix-систем. Но конечно я не смотрел конкретно приведенные там решения, просто я как то надеюсь, что если что то называют x-server то это полноценное управление

Comment: Кстати о мышках.. В описании гуакамоле глаз зацепился за xml-based on-screen keyboard, возможно нормальной клавиатуры там и нет..

Comment: Не далее как на прошлой неделе запускался cockpit у меня в браузере, чтобы графически гулять по удалённому серверу с Fedora 29. Никаких специальных плагинов.

Comment: @0andriy это явно не remote desktop, хотя консоль с командной строкой даёт.  https://www.tecmint.com/cockpit-monitor-multiple-linux-servers-via-web-browser/  Любопытно было б узнать, как это реализовано, имхо без джавы не обошлось..

Comment: @Gybernaty Я не правильно понял вопрос. Подумал, что это всё должно провернутся без участия пользователя со стороны того самого браузера. Но даже в таком варианте всё равно как-то "костыльно", ИМХО. Но спасибо, за поднятый вопрос. Пару новых моментов для себя взял.

Comment: @Mike спасибо за наводку. Постоянно, читаю твои комментарии в разных постах, много дельных вещей пишешь :)

Answer (score 0):

Если погуглить на буржуйском языке, то подобные решения есть и довольно давно. Например:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en

По сути, насколько могу судить, все они сводятся к запуску remote desktop server того или иного разлива на вашей linux машине + использование соответствующего плагина к браузеру на клиенте. Протокол общения, естественно, не http, а один из специально созданных для такой работы (RDP и иже с ним). Т.е. это практически тот же vnc, teamviewer и т.д. просто в окошке браузера.

EDIT: ссылку, что я дал, можно проигнорировать - там только клиенты кросс-платформенные, сервер на Win и Mac. Но искать нужно в этом направлении, если конечно это то, что вас интересует.

Comment: к сожалению это костыль, но уже что то , безусловно задача решаема, но что то уровень руского стека хреноват на нестандартные решения

Comment: :) так пользуйтесь английским. Обрисуйте, что, по-вашему, не костыль. У вас ТЗ недоформулировано. Вот, кстати, очень многообещающее решение https://www.nomachine.com/getting-started-with-web-based-access. Но не на халяву (опять же в ТЗ вопрос цены не упомянут).

Comment: я уже это сделал и мне очень быстро предложили целостное опенсорсное решение , просто мне интересно способствовать тому что бы и в нашем стеке был высокий уровень

Comment: @Gybernaty, уже второй человек говорит, что ты плохо формируешь требования внутри вопроса и просит сказать почему его решение по ссылке - не костыль. Может стоит как-то задуматься над тем КАК задавать вопросы? "мне интересно способствовать тому что бы и в нашем стеке был высокий уровень" - просто закидывая ruSO вопросами и ожидая волшебника на голубом вертолёте?

Comment: ну что ж, посоветовали ему там guacamole. Судя по описанию, тоже достойный продукт. Как и ожидалось, прокладка между браузером и удаленным десктопом. С браузером болтает на http, с десктопом по vnc. Переводчик туда-сюда. Действительно free and open-source, что несомненный плюс. Почему это не костыль, мы, видимо, не дождемся...

Comment: Я в конце напишу актуальное решение которое ятпока не протестил )))

Comment: Да именно на апаче поднимаешь гуакомоле

Comment: Позже выложу конкретно что я сделал

Comment: @Gybernaty чем кстати vnc over java applet не устроил?

Comment: слишком сложну думаю апач будет надежней

Comment: вот ещё https://www.realvnc.com/en/news/control-computer-within-your-web-browser/